# Convert array of hashes to csv

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an array of hashes, like so:

```
[{:id => 1, :name => "test", :status => "active", :desc => "test desc"}, {...}]
```

I need to turn this into a CSV. I realise I could use `CSV.generate` (I'm using ruby 1.9) to generate the CSV.

Would it be an idea to turn the hashes into array's first with `to_a`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
arr = [{:id => 1, :name => "test", :status => "active", :desc => "test desc"},{:x => 4,:l => 7}]
arr = arr.each_with_object([]) { |i,mem| mem << i.to_a  }.flatten
p arr
```

***Output:***

```
[:id, 1, :name, "test", :status, "active", :desc, "test desc", :x, 4, :l, 7]
```

**UPDATE:**

```
  require 'csv'
  arr = [{:id => 1, :name => "test", :status => "active", :desc => "test desc"},{:x => 4,:l => 7}]
  arr = arr.each_with_object([]) { |i,mem| mem << i.to_a}.flatten.to_csv
  p arr
```

***Output:***

```
"id,1,name,test,status,active,desc,test desc,x,4,l,7\n"
```

Comment: How would I apply this to my situation where I have a given `array`? Use `map` to iterate over the `hashes` and call `to_a` on them? Then after that `to_csv` I assume...

Comment: If you could turn it to `csv` with `to_csv` your answer would be complete ;)

Comment: @yossarian Ok,it is done. I was actually confused with the expected output. :) Hope now it is fine completely.